# Downloading and Uploading process template for a single TFS project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

Is there a way to download process template related to one particular project in TFS. I am aware of the "Download" option present at "Team Foundation Server Settings -> Process Template Manager".

Scenario 1

---

I created a project with standard MSF - CMMI process template. But later I added a few reports and custom work item types. Now I need to download the process template so that I can apply it to another project. Is is possible?

Scenario 2

---

If a project is using process template A. Lets say process template B is created after downloading and modifying process template A. Can I apply process template B to an existing project (which was created using template A)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for can not be done. You can try to reconstruct the template by downloading parts of it but you can not download the entire template from an existing project.

As you say in Scenario 1 just take the MSF - CMMI process template and download the additions you made.

You can use [TFS Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBD14EEA-781F-45A1-8C46-9F6BA2F68BF0&displaylang=en) to download custom work items.

Comment: Tigran is correct Scenario 1 and 2 are not possible. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243782.aspx for more help on customizing the Process Template